# Error: "connection to service named com.apple.MapKit.SnapshotService" when starting MKMapSnapshotter

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit, mkmapview

I try to create a snapshot of my map view to display later so I don't have another map view wasting memory.

Most of the time it works just fine, but recently I tried creating a snapshot of Paris and got the Error: "connection to service named com.apple.MapKit.SnapshotService".

I know it looks like a cut a part but no, it seems this is the whole error description.

Full Error:

*Error Domain=MKErrorDomain Code=1 "(null)" UserInfo=.   {NSUnderlyingError=0x284562610 {Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4097     "connection to service named com.apple.MapKit.SnapshotService" UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=connection to service named com.apple.MapKit.SnapshotService}}}*

I've tried multiple times, but it seems when taking a snapshot of Paris it just won't ever work out as it does for other cities. I've really got no clue where I could start solving the problem as I didn't find any information on the origin of my error.

**EDIT: The behaviour actually does appear seemingly random in other cities too.**

In viewDidLoad I initialize my options object like so:

```
snapShotOptions.size = mapView.frame.size
snapShotOptions.scale = UIScreen.main.scale
snapShotOptions.showsBuildings = false
```

When the user now decides to go on, I initialize & start the snapshotter and handle data accordingly, before that I also set the region for the snapshot:

```
snapShotOptions.region = mapView.region
snapShotter = MKMapSnapshotter(options: snapShotOptions)

// Take a snapshot.
snapShotter.start { (snapshot, error) -> Void in
    if error == nil {
        completionHandler(snapshot?.image ?? UIImage())
    } else {
        print(error!)
    }
}
```

I hope someone can help me out here or at least give me a clue as to what the error actually means!

Comment: Are you testing on the Simulator? If so, try a device instead.

Comment: I do test on a device, an iPhone X to be specific

Comment: Maybe just a coincidence, but requesting smaller size snapshots made MKMapSnapshotter more reliable for me.

Answer (score 0):

Recently, I encountered the same phenomenon.
In my case, it happens when I take a snapshot in a situation where a memory warning is occurring.

If this issue has already been resolved, I would be grateful if you could provide information.